# Camera2: Make SurfaceView aspect fit to fill (scaleType CENTER_CROP)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, android-camera2

I've been following the Camera2 example ([android/camera-samples/Camera2Video](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video)) to create an abstraction over the Camera2 library. The idea of my abstraction is to give the user the ability to use a Camera view from React Native, so it's just a `<Camera>` view which can be whatever size/aspect ratio.

While this works out of the box on iOS, I can't seem to get the preview on Android to display "what the camera sees" in the correct aspect ratio.

The official example from Android works like this:

- They create a custom `SurfaceView` extension that should automatically fit to the correct aspect ratio (see: [`AutoFitSurfaceView`](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Video/utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/AutoFitSurfaceView.kt))
- They use that `AutoFitSurfaceView` [in their layout](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Video/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_camera.xml#L22-L25)
- They add a listener to the `AutoFitSurfaceView`'s `Surface` to find out when it has been created ([source](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Video/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L190-L210))
- Once the `Surface` has been created, they call [`getPreviewOutputSize(...)`](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Video/utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/CameraSizes.kt#L50-L79) to get the best matching camera preview size (e.g. so you don't stream 4k for a 1080p screen, that's wasted pixels)
- Then they pass the best matching camera preview size to the [`AutoFitSurfaceView::setAspectRatio(...)`](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Video/utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/AutoFitSurfaceView.kt#L37-L49) function
- By knowing the desired aspect ratio, the `AutoFitSurfaceView` should then automatically perform a center-crop transform in it's [`onMeasure`](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Video/utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/AutoFitSurfaceView.kt#L51-L74) override

If you read the source code of their [`getPreviewOutputSize(...)`](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2Video/utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/CameraSizes.kt#L50-L79) function, you might notice that this uses a `Display` to find the best matching preview size. If I understood the code correctly, this would only work if the camera preview (`AutoFitSurfaceView`) is exactly the same size as the device's screen. This is poorly designed, as there are lots of cases where that simply isn't true. In my case, the Camera has a bit of a bottom spacing/margin, so it doesn't fill the screen and therefore has weird resolutions (1080x1585 on a 1080x1920 screen)

With that long introduction, here comes my question: How do I *actually* perform a correct center crop transform (aka `scaleType = CENTER_CROP`) on my SurfaceView? I've tried the following:

- Set the size of my SurfaceView using [`SurfaceHolder::setFixedSize(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder#setFixedSize(int,%20int)), but that didn't change anything at all
- Remove their `getPreviewOutputSize(...)` stuff and simply use the highest resolution available
- Use the Android View properties `scaleX` and `scaleY` to scale the view by the aspect-ratio difference of the view <-> camera input scaler size (this somewhat worked, but is giving me errors if I try to use high-speed capture: `Surface size 1080x1585 is not part of the high speed supported size list [1280x720, 1920x1080]`)

Any help appreciated!